# google oauth2/calendar getRefreshToken returning NULL

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to allow users to link their google calendar to my system, I've got it mostly working, and actually had it working for a while, but trying to make some modifications it's broken again :(

this page sends them to google:

```
require_once '../../resources/apis/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('../../resources/apis/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/client_secret.json');
$client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/sync/admin/apicomms/gcalmaster/syncFromGoogleCallback.php');
$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

Then the callback goes to here:

```
require_once '../../resources/apis/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('../../resources/apis/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/client_secret.json');
$client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
//$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/sync/admin/broadcast/syncFromGoogleCallback.php');
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

$refresh_token = $client->getRefreshToken();

var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($refresh_token);
```

The callback page is showing

```
array(2) { ["code"]=> string(89) "x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ["scope"]=> string(40) "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar" } NULL
```

So it seems that the authentication is going smoothly, it's not throwing any errors...

What am I missing that is causing me to not get a refresh token? I've checked multiple times under https://myaccount.google.com/permissions to make sure my app isn't currently listed.

EDIT:

I have another script in my app which is currently working, it does the actual synchronisation, pulling the refresh token from the database, getting an access token with it, and succesfully pulling events from the calendar API. The thing that's not currently working is the 'adding' of new calendars to my app, the process of getting a refresh token from a new user

```
$refreshToken = $db->execute('pull refresh token from db');
require_once '../../resources/apis/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('../../resources/apis/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/client_secret.json');
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshTokenFromDB);
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
    'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    //loop through stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

So it looks like you are successful in obtaining an authorization code.

Then with your authorization code you use the:

```
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
```

Keep in mind this is not a token.  It is an authorization code.

You now have to request a access token using the authorization code.

```
$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
```

It's been awhile since I've tinkered around with this, but I think that this is also your only time that you will be able to request a refresh token.

So you will want to do this line next:

```
 $refreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();
```

You will want to securely save these tokens in a json file somewhere on your system to use the next time you want to do something with this calendar.

So when you do use this again, you will use the $accessToken to establish your credentials with google.  If that access token is expired you will have to use the refresh token to get a new access token.  I'm pretty sure the refresh token stays constant.  If not it will be sent with the new access token.  Then you re-save the json file.  Rinse and repeat.

UPDATED

You will use:

```
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refresh_token);
```

To obtain a new access token.

Comment: I've added `$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();` just above my line `$refresh_token = $client->getRefreshToken();` but both are showing as NULL when I var_dump them. I seem to still have an issue upstream somewhere

Comment: What calendar are you trying to access

Comment: You may need to sign into that calendar and remove the permissions for your API and try again.

Comment: I'm using my personal one for testing, I've made sure I've removed the permissions

Comment: Is the OAuth2 flow being followed.  ie, You get redirected to a google account page where it asks you for permission.  You click yes, it redirects you back to a page on your site?  Is that process happening?

Comment: @Kelly Larsen I see your update.  So you log in to your site, and you attempt to add your own personal calendar.  When you try to add a calendar does it redirect you to a google page where it asks you to allow your api to have access to your calendar.  You click yes, and then it redirects you to another page on your site.  Is this process happening at all?

Comment: yep, that process is working, running the first block of code takes me to the page where my currently logged in google accounts are listed. clicking on one of those shows a page saying "myserver.co.nz wants to access your Google Account xxxx@gmail.com This will allow myserver.co.nz to Manage your calendars". clicking allow takes me back to the callback page where I get the authorisation code as a $_GET variable, but trying to get access and refresh tokens is just giving me NULL

Comment: Can't find a way to pm you so I'll just post here, I finally figured it out lol! I had moved the files and updated the setRedirectUri on the first page from '/sync/admin/broadcast/syncFromGoogleCallback.php' to '/sync/admin/apicomms/gcalmaster/syncFromGoogleCallback.php', but hadn't updated it on the callback page (DO'OH!)
It's weird that it wasn't throwing an error... Oh well, it's working, thank you again for the time you spent helping :)

Comment: Hey no problem.  It was good for me to revisit the google code anyways.  I would be lying to you if I said I've never done that same thing.  I'm glad you have it figured it.  Good luck with the rest of project.  Cheers!